# How to get the passes of O1, O2, O3 in LLVM?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization

I'm new for llvm.

I wonder how to get the passes of ON.

I know there is a flag `opt -O3 -debug-pass-manager` to get the detail, but it is too "detail" and I just want to know the order of passes ON use.

On the other hand, How to know the passes of ON in the form like `mem2reg, due, always-inline...` or where is the document that describe about it?

I can't find it. This problem takes me too long. I want to compare the orders between them and mine.

Comment: I found that by grepping for a few of the pass names I used. Each pass was mentioned in a few files: Some test files, the pass itself and only a few others. I looked at those others, and soon enough found a large function with several if()s that added the passes for O1/O2/O3. I'm sure it's moved since I did it, but it was simple.

Comment: ```-debug-pass=Arguments``` flag should do what you want.